# Axios GET request resulting in CORS error

Tags: vue.js, cors, axios

I'm working on a VueJS app, and I want to use the Yahoo! Shopping API (documentation: https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/shopping/shopping/v1/itemsearch.html) to fetch products using their barcode. However, I keep getting a CORS error and I'm not sure why, or what I can do to make it work. My code is as follows:

```
data() {
  return {
    appId: 'dj00aiZpPUQ4RTBUUTVSNUs3TyZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9NTI-',
    apiUrl: 'https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch'
  }
}

...

axios.get(this.apiUrl, {
  params: {
    appid: this.appId,
    jan: 4589707054951
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
  alert(error)
})
```

The specific error I get is this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch?appid=dj00aiZpPUQ4RTBUUTVSNUs3TyZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9NTI-&jan=4589707054951'
>   from origin 'https://0.0.0.0:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

What can I do to make this work? So far the only way it works is using the CORS Chrome extension, but that's naturally just for testing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are trying to access a third party API. So you will not be able to set CORS headers in that API , you should create a consumer API for you with CORS enabled for your and consume this third party API from that API.

Answer (score 0):

The server/api owner needs to send this in his response header:
Or if you have a server settings panel or something, make sure to add the domain from where you are making the request.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'your-domain-here'.

Please read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I solved it in the following manner.

This error occurs because we are tryign to access the data hosted on a different server. CORS issue is a browser issue where a certain browser does allow you to access the contents hosted on a different or a virtual server. If you observe the app that you are running on is on the local-host (https://0.0.0.0:8080) and trying to access the data hosted on https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch. You can solve this problem simply by adding in a few lines of code in your vue application.

Step 1: 
Create a new file called vue.config.js in your root directory of the vue application, that is beside your package.json file. Add the following code in your vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
   devServer:{
   proxy: "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp" 
  }
}
```

Note: https://shopping.yahooapis.jp would be your base url.

Step 2: 
Now, go back to your code in data(). Replace the domain name/base url of the apiUrl with https://0.0.0.0:8080. that is now your apiUrl would be https://0.0.0.0:8080/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch.

```
data() {
  return {
    appId: 'dj00aiZpPUQ4RTBUUTVSNUs3TyZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9NTI-',
    apiUrl: 'https://0.0.0.0:8080/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch'
  }
}
```

Step 3: 
Restart your application. Eg, npm run serve.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which worked without creating a proxy server or a mock server. You can disable the security settings for accessing cross origin apis on your web browser.

You can disable the **CHROME** security settings for accessing apis out of the origin by typing the below command on the terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security
```

After running the above command on your terminal, a new chrome window with security settings disabled will open up. Now, run your program (npm run serve / npm run dev) again and this time you will not get any CORS error and would be able to GET request using axios.

Hope this helps!